# How to return both null and not-null values in one query

Tags: sql, null

I have an integer field person_id with the default value of NULL. I am using a stored procedure and pulling people names and address. if a user does not pass a value all records are pulled both, null and not nulls. How do I do it. May be Case statement or otherwise?

```
my_procedure(          <--- this is pseudo code
@person_id int null
begin
select name, address from PERSON
WHERE person_id like case NULL then NULL else '%'
end
```

Null requires -> IS NULL
number requires = 123

**EDIT**
I need a condition too, if nothing is passed, all values are pulled. If something is passed, that value is searched

Comment: For the edit, you need to give more information.

Comment: Solved: IsNULL(mycolum,'') LIKE CASE  when atperson_id is null then '%' else '%' + atperson_id + '%'

Comment: post an answer and accept it.  Or delete it, since it's still not really clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I just discovered a bug in stackvoerflow, if you place @ it thinks you are aiming at a user. With two @ you can't post your comment. You can't post two @ followed by a word immediately.

Comment: Post that on Meta.  It also not omits the @ if it will automatically go to that user anyways.

Comment: I can't post asnwer to my question for 6 hours or so. Wont delete it, someone else can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code in this case is

```
IsNULL(mycolum,'') LIKE CASE when person_id is null then '%' else '%' + person_id + '%'
```

IsNULL coverts *null* values into empty string and then you can worry about only strings, not null values.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE (@personID is NULL OR personid IS NULL OR personid = @personid)`

Just put both your cases in a parenthetical `WHERE` clause.

**EDIT**

Added another `OR` clause to cover what I **THINK** you are asking for.